# PDFMake how to get current column number of the table?

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

I want to conditionally render different border depending on cell number. But I get the `hLineStyle` only with `i` and `node` value. Is there a way to obtain current cell number? MY desired output as below.

```
hLineStyle: function (i, node) {
  return i === 2 ? { dash: { length: 1, space: 1 } } : "black"; // both lines dotted
},
```

[image]